# Why this won't bring the image to the center and middle at vertical position?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

This shows the image. I'd like to show the image in center and middle at vertical position.
But this still shows it on top and lefted.
How can I fix?

```
<div class="Row">

    <div class="Box">

        <div class="Left">

            <div class="title"><a href="/communities/california">California</a></div>

            <div class="icon" style=";vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">
                    <a href="/users/John"><img alt="356" src="/images/356.jpg" style="max-width: 100px; min-width: 100px" /></a>
            </div>

            <div class="message">
                <div class="body"><a data-original-title="California" class="btn" rel="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Test">Read</a></div>
                    <a href="/users/sign_in" class="btn btn-primary">Message</a>    
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<div class="Row">

    <div class="Box">

        <div class="Left">

            <div class="title"><a href="/communities/california">California</a></div>

            <div class="icon" style="display: table;">
                    <a href="/users/John"><img alt="356" src="/images/356.jpg" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;" /></a>
            </div>

            <div class="message">
                <div class="body"><a data-original-title="California" class="btn" rel="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Test">Read</a></div>
                    <a href="/users/sign_in" class="btn btn-primary">Message</a>    
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot vertically align an element just like that, you need to `display: table-cell` nested under element having `display: table;` property. I've made an example from scratch here which will help you with the issue you are currently encountering.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/efTy3/)

```
div.wrap {
    display: table;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}

div.wrap span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Please see my update. I fixed it following your suggestion but it still shows the same:(

Comment: @HUSTEN can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use external styling for CSS. It makes it much easier to change

Second, the reason it isn't aligning vertically is because `vertical-align:middle` only works on tables. So if you give it a property of `display:table-cell`, it will work for you. This is one of many ways to center vertically.

Third, to conquer the horizontal alignment, try changing `text-align:center` to `margin:0 auto`. Or you could set the `text-align` to the parent. Also, assuming from the class `left`, it sounds like it should be positioned at the left

Comment: I added update to my question following Mr.Alien's suggestion. But it's still the same:(

Comment: Put the styles on the `a` as opposed to the `img`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

**CSS**

```
#myoutercontainer {
    position: relative
}
#myinnercontainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 10em;
    margin-top: -5em
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="myoutercontainer">
    <div id="myinnercontainer">
        <p>Hey look! I'm vertically centered!</p>
        <p>How sweet is this?!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

As Cody mentioned *vertical-align* cannot be used in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can vertical align the image by using

```
padding:30px 0;
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NXhmy/)